# Retrofit 2 returns null in release APK when minifyenable but ok in debug APK

Tags: android, retrofit2

Getting null response but code 200 with Release APK when minify enable, when minify false then its ok.

[image]

But getting expected response with debug APK when minify enable.

Comment: What is your question? Where is the code? What is the response? What is the expected response? Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: getting null response in release APK for only one API but other API's are fine 
When all API's are working fine in debug APK.

Can you suggest anything about it ?

Comment: All that was already said in your title. You didn't answer any of the questions.

Comment: Getting same null response from response.body() of onResponse() in release build. Using retrofit2, gradle version 4.1.1, studio 4.1.1

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Problem solved :)

No issue with proguard-rules no need to add anything extra.

Needed to add SerializedName annotation if minifyEnabled even if variable name same as key.

That was the only Model which i had created manually :P

Which works fine in Debug but not after Signed in. :)

Comment: i am not getting successful response from retrofit on adding SerializedName annotation.

Comment: Geeez! I'm trying to solve this for 3 days already. Good thing I read your answer. Thanks for this man!

Comment: Wow, how could you find this solution, you saved me to getting crazy. thanks.

Comment: It works for me but: why GSON not deserialize classes when minifyEnable = true?

Comment: It obfuscates the code by changing class/variable names.

Comment: Omg, took me several weeks, no idea why this is happening , you saved me too

Comment: I am using @Body to send body for the post endpoint. not sure how to add serialized name to this :(

Comment: @mohammadrezasarsarabi no need to serialize that body, it will work.

Comment: @JahangirKabir actually when minifyEnabled was set to true, that body element was ignored in release apk. I fixed it by removing minifyEnabled true.

Comment: you saved me , no need to serialize all the parameters for just one and its work like a charm

Comment: i have pojo classes in different different location for each screen api request and response working perfect in debug but that pojos not working in released.  what is the issue?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and my solution was to modify the 'protection rules' to exclude your class from obfuscation.

```
-keep public class com.your.packages.model.** {*;}
```

Comment: My app was in production with 38k active users , the fastest solution was to set minifyenabled to false.. the size was 2.5mb ,, now its 5mb ..i will test your solution now..

Comment: i wnat to set this for whole app is ti possible ?

Comment: @PrakashShukla Above solution worked or not?

Answer (score 3):

```
-keep public class com.your.packages.model.* {*;}
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup proguard-rule for release. If you want to test real server, you can create new build type, which targets server API

Cheers :)

Comment: I have added proguard-rule also but no hope.
Cause only one API is not working but others are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've identified the issue in your code. Adding `minifyEnabled false` in the release build configuration disables code minification. Minification is a process that reduces the size of your code by removing unnecessary characters and renaming variables, which can sometimes lead to issues, especially in release builds.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
        
Copy At proguard-rules.pro ^^^^^^

/////////////////////////////////
package com.*;//

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;// <<
        
public class Retrofit { 
  @SerializedName("name") //<<<<
  private String apiname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()//--> Remove this line this might be an issue there
            .disableInnerClassSerialization()
            .create();
```

Here is the solution if you have code like this. **It worked**

**

> .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()//--> Remove this line this
> might be an issue there

**

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution shared by @Juanes30 worked:

-keep public class com.your.packages.model.** {*;}

Other solutions or even Retrofit docs didn't work.

Comment: Answer could have applied code style

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31897855)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this this line `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` in build.gradle. Then **replace this line** with

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
```

With this code, you can also use **minifyEnabled** and **shrinkResources**.

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
```

Then their is also no need `proguard-rules.txt` file in app folder.