# Null Response in Signed APK - Proper response in Debug APK

Tags: android, json, debugging, apk, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit for network calls.

I am facing weird issue with signed APK.

Retrofit request,

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@POST("******")
Call<UserInfoResponse> authenticateUser(@Field("umMobileNumber") String websiteId,
                                    @Field("spPassword") String loginSource);
```

In the response of the above request, I am getting the proper response, If I am running it on debug build.

But the same thing if I do with Signed APK, I am getting a null object in the response.

Response below,

```
{
"isValid": true,
"accessToken": "",
"isValidToken": true,
"serviceBean": {
    },
"customerExist": false,
"singleSessionFlag": false
 }
```

In Singed Apk I am getting serviceBean as null.

Not getting any solution on the google.

Can someone help me out in resolving this?

Comment: include your actual function header (so either `void request(blabla)` or `fun request()`)

Comment: Have you configured your Proguard file properly ? It's possible you might not have kept proper classes for Retrofit 2 in your proguard. Check this https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-retrofit2.pro

Comment: @Zun I have updated my request. Can you please check it out.

Comment: @MayRestinPeace I added the proguard code, but still same issue

Comment: Add Your Response Model - UserInforResponse

Comment: @m3g4tr0n I have added the response

Comment: Add your UserInforResponse class

Answer (score 5):

please set minify as false. (Build/Edit Buildtype)
if you set this option when code release, some part is removed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I removed `tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode"` in **AndroidManifest.xml**, which I added for debugging.

After made the above change, received proper response from Retrofit request in Signed APK.

Note: I know this is a late reply and I am posting it for someone facing similar problem in future.

Comment: i remove this , still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are building release apk then there will be proguard rule will be applied. Proguard will obfuscate you class file.

In your build.gradle(app)

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

try to remove this rule

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

and re-build release apk.If it is working then it is issue with proguard rule.

Comment: In the release build minifyEnabled has to be true right?

Comment: @hasan_shaikh : no minifyEnable should be false.Because if you make it true, it will required to add proguard.

Comment: Yes, In release build minifyEnabled should be set true, it minifies your code and makes it harder for attacker to reverse engineer your code

Answer (score 1):

I added SerializedName annotation to all fields in my version of UserInfoResponse class as suggested in [Retrofit 2 returns null in release APK when minifyenable but ok in debug APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782328/retrofit-2-returns-null-in-release-apk-when-minifyenable-but-ok-in-debug-apk). Still did not solve the problem.

Adding

-keep class UserInfoResponse { *; }

rule in proguard rules fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
//add into proguard rules

-keep public class com.AppName.PackageName.response/modelClassPath.** {*;}

//add into gradle:app

buildTypes {
        release {
                minifyEnabled   true
                shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with deserialization,

I solved it by following this,

[Retrofit 2 returns null in release APK when minifyenable but ok in debug APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782328/retrofit-2-returns-null-in-release-apk-when-minifyenable-but-ok-in-debug-apk)