# Android Release Connecting to Web API

Tags: android, google-signin

I have built an Android app running on Android 10 and below.  The app uses Google Sign In.  In debug it works perfectly.  In release it does not.

In my Firebase console I have set the debug SHA1, my local release key SHA1, and the app release SHA1 from the Google play console.  One further point, on the Android when running the release apk the app it receives a Google token after the Google Login button is clicked.  If I quickly take this token and hit my web api, the app will authenticate with that token.  I "believe" I have exhausted the possibilities that it could be an SHA1 key issue. The release version does not hit the web api at all.  The debug and release versions both use the same API so there is no possibility of going to different URL's in different versions.

Also, according to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=wr.significantdigits.com Android should not have a problem hitting the site.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting minify false solved my problem.  My posted object was not being passed to the web api.  Somehow the minify setting was allowing Android Studio to include what it wanted??

[Null Response in Signed APK - Proper response in Debug APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255281/null-response-in-signed-apk-proper-response-in-debug-apk)